# Displaying multiple windows in Mayavi

Tags: python-3.x, plot, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I'm trying to plot multiple figures in separate windows in Mayavi

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np


# @mlab.show()
def do(x, y, z, fig):
    mlab.figure(fig)
    mlab.plot3d(x, y, z)
    mlab.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    do(x=np.random.rand(10), y=np.random.rand(10), z=np.random.rand(10), fig=1)
    do(x=np.random.rand(10), y=np.random.rand(10), z=np.random.rand(10), fig=2)
```

The second window is displayed only after I close the window of the first figure. Any suggestions on how to display both the windows?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you have `mlab.show()` inside `do`. If you put `mlab.show()` after you call `do` the last time, I think that should work.